# Napili Template Lightning Custom Sign Up page from community without login

Tags: customer-community, community-builder, napili

I have created a lightning signup component for the community and am using it on the Napili template home page via community builder. Now, I want to make this page accessible to community users without login but I'm not getting any option to make it available for the user without login. I configured the registration page setting of community with the Napili template home page but still seeing the login page rather than the registration page as shown in below screenshots:

[image: Community setup to see community builder created Napili template page as registration/loginpage]

[image: Napili Home Page with sign up lightening component]

Also, I am not getting an option to select "Napili template home page" as login page for the community, if I could this might help me to see this home page without login. Am I missing any setting here?

Comment: Can you check username and password checkbox on the Administration > Login &Registration page in Community Management? If it is unchecked it may be the reason that is not visible to you.

Comment: Yes, we have a page level Access setting **Page Access** adjust it as per your requirement. Also, don't forget to _publish_ the changes;

Comment: Yes, already tried this but didn't resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your public can access the community under Settings>General :

[image]

Afterwards, validate the settings under community management as you pointed out in your screenshots.

Comment: I already tried this option but it didn't help me out.

Comment: Hey guys, 

I have tried now to check 'Allow internal users to log in directly to the community'  option in the community and now I am able to access to "Napili" home page having a sign-up lightening component from anywhere without login. But still searching for the way to access any page of the community without login same as accessing now the home page. Is there any setting through which we can do it?